# Confusion in Begin Tran and commit Tran

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As per my knowledge if we start statement with begin tran/ commit tran it will be completely done or nothing. But when I am executing below TSQL code it updates the record for first table n do nothing neither commit not rollback.I have also tried if @@error<> 0 but its also not working..Please help me out.

```
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE A SET NAME ='ABC' WHERE ID=2

INSERT INTO TTT VALUES('GJ')

COMMIT TRAN

TABLE TTT DOES NOT EXIST.
```

I have used this table to throw an error in this block of code.

Comment: Where do you "inform" to the transaction to rollback on error? I don't see that line of code.

Comment: How do you know the record has been updated? Did you check from the same session or another session?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is partially correct, partially incorrect.

A transaction remains open until it is committed or rolled back. You can commit or roll back manually (`COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`), and there are some cases where transactions are rolled back automatically. You're not rolling back manually, and there isn't anything to force an automatic rollback on your particular system.

For code like yours, the [`SET XACT_ABORT ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx) option is useful: this causes errors to automatically roll back the current transaction.

Comment: Is the below code is correct.. I'm getting same result in below code also.. Thanks in advance  BEGIN
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE T1 SET refid ='VIN23456Y'  
INSERT INTO TTT VALUES ('SDFS')
IF(@@ERROR<>0)
    BEGIN
      
     ROLLBACK
       
    END
   ELSE
    BEGIN
     
     commit TRAN
     
    END
    
END

Comment: @VimalKumarPrajapati It's not. You're assuming you get to the point where you can check for errors, but if the error is serious enough, you won't get that far.

Comment: You can get the list of the currently open transactions for the selected database with `DBCC OPENTRAN` or for all databvases: `SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE open_tran = 1`. Check if your connection has open transactions.

Comment: @Pred If you're going to check for your own process, just use `@@TRANCOUNT` -- but there's no need to check.

Comment: Thank You sooo much hvd. So, the "Invalid object name" is kind of serious error. what else belong to serious error category..

Comment: @VimalKumarPrajapati A quick search brings up http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#statementbatch

Comment: Thats a Great link @hvd..Thank a lot for sharing this with me :)